# Getting ?(Question mark) character for è, Ä, É, Ó, Nº, ú, Ö charactrers in pdf

Tags: c#, fonts, pdf-generation, itext7

I am generating pdf templates from html text. I am getting '?'(question mark) character for few characters like è, Ä, É, Ó, Nº, ú, Ö etc in the generated pdf.

```
string font = @"\SEGOEUI.TTF";
FontProvider fp = new DefaultFontProvider(false, false, false);
FontProgram defaultFont = FontProgramFactory.CreateFont(font);
fp.AddFont(defaultFont);

ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties(); 
properties.SetFontProvider(fp);
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Note:
These characters are shown properly in the input text(html).

Comment: change encoding to unicode

Comment: What vasily wrote, + double-check if your desired font has defined those characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PDF you need to specify encodings for fonts that you are using. Default encoding in `FontProvider` depends on the font type - for `Type1` fonts it is `PdfEncodings.WINANSI`, in other cases it is `PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H`.

It is not clear which font is used in PDF when your `html` is converted, but in any case if you are using characters with diacritics and other characters from different ranges of Unicode, you should use `addFont(FontProgram fontProgram, String encoding)` overload to specify the encoding explicitly and use `PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H` encoding.

So in your case it should be

```
fp.AddFont(defaultFont, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
```